# Littlefs based on W25Q256 can not open a large number of files

Tags: c, file, flash, spi

**I use littlefs on W25Q256 to manage my file. When I use littlefs which on Github "tests/test_files.toml" it has problem.
At the beginning code run correct and "open_return" = 0 "read_return" = 7; When the code "for (int i = 0; i < MANY_FILES_N; i++)" i run to 63 it suspended and lasts for 20seconds. Then "open_return" = -2 and "read_return" = -84.
When I change ".read_size" = 64, ".prog_size" = 64, the error will be quick as i run to 31. I don not konw where has the problem, maybe littlefs interrupt function, maybe w25q, maybe spi. I know littlefs is an uncommon file system. I can not use it well. **

```
enter code here
```

void many_files_test()
{

```
    uint8_t *path = rt_malloc(20);

    format_return = lfs_format(&lfs, &lfs_cfg);
    
    mount_return = lfs_mount(&lfs, &lfs_cfg);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        
        sprintf(path, "file_%03d", i);
        
        open_return = lfs_file_open(&lfs, &lfs_file, path,
                  LFS_O_WRONLY | LFS_O_CREAT | LFS_O_EXCL);
        
        size = 7;
        snprintf(wbuffer, size, "Hi %03d", i);
        write_return = lfs_file_write(&lfs, &lfs_file, wbuffer, size);
       
        close_return = lfs_file_close(&lfs, &lfs_file);
        

        for(uint16_t file_count = 0; file_count < i + 1; file_count++)
        {
            sprintf(path, "file_%03d", file_count);
            open_return = lfs_file_open(&lfs, &lfs_file, path, LFS_O_RDONLY);
           
            read_return = lfs_file_read(&lfs, &lfs_file, rbuffer, size);
            
            close_return = lfs_file_close(&lfs, &lfs_file);
           
        }
    }
    unmount_return = lfs_unmount(&lfs);
   
    rt_free(path);
}
```

Comment: "for (int i = 0; i < MANY_FILES_N; i++)" means "for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)"

Comment: What is the OS limit on max open files?

Comment: I run the code on arm processor and no OS.